# ISTQB Question clarification

Tags: manual-testing, istqb, application-software-testing

Question:- Consider the following statements

> i. an incident may be closed without being fixed
>
> ii. incidents may not be raised against documentation
>
> iii. the final stage of incident tracking is fixing
>
> iv. the incident record does not include information on test environments
>
> v. incidents should be raised when someone other than the author of the software performs the test

- a) ii and v are true, i, iii and iv are false
- b) i and v are true, ii, iii and iv are false
- c) i, iv and v are true, ii and iii are false
- d) i and ii are true, iii, iv and v are false
- e) i is true, ii, iii, iv and v are false

The given answer is 'b'.

'i' is true, that is fine, but how is it that 'v' is also true? I need an explanation for that, Please some one help me on this.

Comment: v is somewhat obscure. Incidents should be raised when a problem in the software is detected, and it doesn't matter who performed the test.

Comment: an incident can also be a system outage, so I am with you on that point.

Answer (score 0):

What 'v' is saying is that you should have no conflict of interest, a separation of labour, or job roles

I would take issue with this answer if it is given in absolute terms, but it isn't. :)

Comment: I see my answer is voted down. Almost everything posted for the last hour has been voted down. If there is a reason for the downvote, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Some (not me) in our community see it as their responsibility to down-vote.  They mean well and wish to keep quality high.  But they do it too much (remember not nec 1 person) and it affects new folks negatively.  I've gotten used to it. sort of.

Comment: To be honest it looks like somebody developed a script to do it.

Comment: I upvoted both answers to counteract the downvotes without explanations.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is B.

Explanation as follows,

1. Incident may be a feature. because of the miscommunication in the documentation, It was raised as an incident. SO it's possible to close it.
2. Given documentation should be correct and testing takes a place accordingly.
3. The final stage of the Incident is not always a fixing . just like I mentioned in 1) it can be closed without fixing.
4. The incident record must give information about the test environment.
5. here, " someone other than the author of the software" as developers. Not developers. others can perform tests.

Comment: In the question, he was told the answer was B. Are you saying the syllabus gives E as the correct answer?

Comment: edited my answer. pls, refer. @SlightlyKosumi